# Get likes, comments, shares for post ID

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using Linked [Share](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) API to share posts on LinkedIn accounts.

After post is shared, LinkedIn returns the ID of the post.
Now I want to use that ID and call the LinkedIn API to get count of shares, comments and likes for that post.

But I cannot find anything in their documentation. Is there a way for me to get these data?

The endpoint which I use to share post on LinkedIn is:
[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E/shares)

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to share a post?

Comment: @Veve Check may update in question

Comment: Your update didn't showed us the code you used.